# SQL Server 2019 - CU 13 Problem with Memory Optimized Table Type

Tags: sql-server

I recently installed CU 13 on my test SQL Server 2019 server.

Now, when running CheckDB I'm getting a consistency error with a simple memory optimized table type.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ADUserType] AS TABLE(
    [UserId] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](300) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (UserId)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)
GO

DBCC CHECKDB (MyDatabase) WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
```

"Verified integrity of statistics 'sys.TT_ADUserType_094028A5.PK__TT_ADUse__1788CC4D0F98FE70'.
Msg 9122, Level 16, State 201, Line 17
The statistics 'sys.TT_ADUserType_094028A5.PK__TT_ADUse__1788CC4D0F98FE70' is corrupt."

Is this a bug in the update?  Or do I need to create the type differently?

Thanks!

Comment: [KB4530907 - Improvement: Corrupted statistics can be detected by using extended_logical_checks in SQL Server 2016, 2017, and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4530907-improvement-corrupted-statistics-can-be-detected-by-using-extended-logical-checks-in-sql-server-2016-2017-and-2019-c5369ce6-9c2d-3993-6c79-2a1e863f8e14)

Comment: @ErikDarling OP is on CU13 already, and is using `EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS` so I don't see how that's relevant, other than why there is more info than there used to be. It's kind of weird that a Table type has statistics anyway, and what exactly could corrupt them? Table types can only be used for table variables which have no statistics

Comment: @charlieface yes, OP asked if it was a bug in CU13. I understand your points otherwise, but I don’t have any more details.

Comment: Thanks for providing the KB4530907 information. Our nightly CheckDB job has been running with EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS for years with no problems. I was also surprised when it flagged a table type after the CU update. I use this MEMORY_OPTIMIZED table type to load a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED table from a non memory optimized table.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error. Rebuilding indexes and repairing the database did not resolve it.